# how to get value image on table row class name in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am editing table row in Jquery and the value i get from `table row` i set it to form's textfield ,but when to get value of image and set it to form input file does not work ,please help me :

```
$(".editBtn").click(function() {

// get table row value
var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
var $site_ = $row.find(".site_name").text(); 
var $photo = $row.find(".photo").file(); // Find the image file

// set table row values to the form 

  document.getElementById("site").value = $site_ ;
  document.getElementById("pto").value = $photo ;
  });
```

html code :

```
...
    <tr>
              <th>No</th>
              <th>Site name</th>
            <th>Photo</th>            
            <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>

                <?php
      //set counter variable
        $counter = 1;
        while($userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $counter  ?></td>
              <td class="site_name"><?php echo $userRow['site_name']; ?></td>
              <td class="photo"><?php echo '<img src="data:photo/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($userRow['photo'] ).'" height="50"/><br/>'  ; ?></td>


    ....
```

Form used to get table row to be edited :

```
 ...............
 <!-- Modal  for edit -->

      <form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="<?php echo 
      $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" autocomplete="off">


        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="">Touristic site name</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="site" type="text" aria-describedby="" 
  name="site_name" placeholder="Touristic site name" required="true"><br>

        </div>
      </div>


       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="">photo</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="pto" type="file" accept="image/*" aria-describedby="" name="photo" placeholder="photo" required="true"/><br>
          </div>

   .........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you believe that the `.file()` function exists ? Did you check the documentation ? I guess no : http://api.jquery.com/?s=file. Programming is not magic.

```js
var img = $("#container").find("img");
console.log(img.attr("src"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHT2C.jpg" height="120">
</div>
```